# drop down unique search for labels

Tags: php, mysql

My table has a column named Labels.

```
1 work
2 work, fun
3 fun, adventure
4 disney, fun
```

I created a drop down search for labels but I see all words like work work fun fun fun adventure disney. I tried to do distinct but could not work it out. Help Please...

```
<?php 
  include("config1.php");
  $sql = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT Labels FROM bookmark_app group BY Labels ');
  //echo "<select name='term' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
  $models = array();
  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    $my_arr = explode(",", $rows['Labels']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_arr); $i++) { 
      // echo "$my_arr[$i]</br>";
      // $models[] = $rows;
      $models[]= $my_arr[$i]; 
    }
  }
  //print_r($models);
  exit; 
?>
```

Comment: Attach your code and table structure/data

Comment: '<?php
include("config1.php"); 

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT Labels FROM  bookmark_app group BY Labels ');

$models = array();

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$my_arr = explode(",", $rows['Labels']); 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_arr); $i++) {

      $models[]= $my_arr[$i]; 
 }
}



?>'

Comment: @user2662372: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The information in your comment should be added to the question. I've edited the question, copied the code from your comment, and tried to reformat the code as best I could.

Comment: The first step would be to [normalize your data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). However, here a proper `trim` would be of help.

Comment: FYI: your query doesn't need both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`. One or the other is sufficient. (That's not an answer to your question, just a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($my_arr); $i++) { 
        if(in_array($my_arr[$i],$models)){ // added
            continue;
        }
      $models[]= $my_arr[$i]; 
    }
```